# Subtraction on PHP return 0

Tags: php, rounding

I have a function in PHP which calculate the distance with longitude and latitude in parameters.

```
//Convert to kilometers
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) 
{
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; //$lon1 = 1.451785000 and $lon 2 = 1.451628000 (should return -0.000157)
  echo $theta; //Display "0" instead of "-0.000157"

  $dist  = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist  = acos($dist);
  $dist  = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit  = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } 
  else if ($unit == "N") {
    return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } 
  else {
    return $miles;
  }
}
```

The problem is that $theta returns 0 instead of the real result -0.000157.

I think it is because PHP assumes that this number is too tiny so it rounds it to 0.

Is there a function to avoid that ?

Comment: Yes, it probably is due to precision of numbers and errors accumulating during calculations
You should force the use of floats from the beginning: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: I think your assumptions about whats inside `$lon1` and `$lon2` are incorrect. The subtraction gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem !

I had to use the following code :

```
bcsub($lon1, $lon2, 10);
```

It subtracts the 2 numbers and set the number of digits after the decimal place in the result (10 here).

Answer (score 0):

I think `ini_set('precision', 17)` is what you are looking for.